# Recaptcha 2.0 validation failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing problem with Recaptcha 2.0. Its working fine untill I click the button to check for validation. But it always executing the else block and showing "Validation failed.".Am I missing something.Please Help.

In aspx,

```
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="?" method="post" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Public_Key"></div>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonCheck" runat="server" Text="Check" OnClick="ButtonCheck_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="LabelMessage" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Then a classs,

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public string success { get; set; }
    }
```

Then In Code Behind File,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ButtonCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Page.IsValid)
            {
                if(CheckValidation())
                {
                    LabelMessage.Text = "You are ready to go.";
                }
                else
                {
                    LabelMessage.Text = "Validation Failed.";
                }
            }
        }
        public bool CheckValidation()
        {
            string Response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
            bool Valid = false;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=Private_Key &response=" + Response);
            try
            {
                using(WebResponse webResponse=request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using(StreamReader streamReader=new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string jasonResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        MyObject data = js.Deserialize<MyObject>(jasonResponse);
                        Valid = Convert.ToBoolean(data.success);
                    }
                }
                return Valid;
            }
            catch(WebException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: yes.And i saw that Request["g-recaptcha-response"]; it does not taking any thing.It always remains null. and I have no idea how to catch the response.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to display Google Recaptcha on your WebForm by adding Reference to reCaptcha DLL into asp .net application.

Get your recaptcha keys from [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#whyrecaptcha).

Step 1: Download reCaptcha DLL. You can download latest reCaptcha DLL from this [link](https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:aspnetlib-Latest).

Step 2: Unzip the archived folder. After unzipping the archived folder you will see following files.
[image]

Step 3: Add refrence to reCaptcha DLL.

[image]

Browse Recaptcha DLL

[image]

Select DLL File

[image]

Step 4: Register reCaptcha to asp .net webpage by adding Tagprefix.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>
```

Step 5: Add reCaptcha Code into webpage

```
<asp:label id="lblResult" runat="server"></asp:label>
    <recaptcha:recaptchacontrol id="RecaptchaControl2" runat="server" publickey="Paste-Your-Public-Kye-here" privatekey="Pase-Your-Private-Key-Here" theme="blackglass"></recaptcha:recaptchacontrol>
    <asp:button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:button>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RecaptchaControl2.IsValid)
    {
        lblResult.Text = "You Got It!";
        lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Incorrect";
        lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's again the same thing. No matter what i do,it always executing the else block and showing "Incorrect" message.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try `RecaptchaControl2.IsValid` instead of `Page.IsValid`. It will solved your problem.

Comment: Keval, will your solution work if the recaptcha is inside an UpdatePanel?

Comment: @paparush Not sure because this is very old Google recaptcha. I think you need to go with the latest recaptcha of Google.